# How can I do paging and sorting in a Perl CGI program?

Tags: html, perl, cgi

Here is the table in which I am retrieving the data from an SQLite database.
Its having lots of records, so near that ADD button I need something like
`|< <  > >|` which would do the paging function whenever I click. 
Also, besides the table each header (e.g. UserName UserId) I need a sorting 
button. Something like a `^` button. Please do help me find the solution..Thank You.

```
  #!C:\perl\bin\perl.exe

  use CGI;
  use CGI qw/:standard/;
  use CGI::Carp qw(warningsToBrowser fatalsToBrowser);
  my $q = new CGI;
  use DBI;
  use CGI qw(:all);
  use warnings;
  print $q->header ( );
  my $dbh = DBI->connect(
        "dbi:SQLite:DEVICE.db",
        "", "",
        {
            RaiseError => 1,
            AutoCommit => 1
        }
    );
  my @rows = ();
  my $sql = "SELECT UserId,UserName,CardNo,GroupId,Role,VerifyType FROM UsersList";
  my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql) or die("\n\nPREPARE ERROR:\n\n$DBI::errstr");
  $sth->execute or die("\n\nQUERY ERROR:\n\n$DBI::errstr");
  print '<table>';
  print "<tr>";
  print "<th>$sth->{NAME}->[0]</th>";
  print "<th>$sth->{NAME}->[1]</th>";
  print "<th>$sth->{NAME}->[2]</th>";
  print "<th>$sth->{NAME}->[3]</th>";
  print "<th>$sth->{NAME}->[4]</th>";
  print "<th>$sth->{NAME}->[5]</th>";
  print "<th>  EDIT  </th>";
  print "<th>  DELETE  </th>";

  while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
  print "
  <tr>
  <td>$row[0]</td>
  <td>$row[1]</td>
  <td>$row[2]</td>
  <td>$row[3]</td>
  <td>$row[4]</td>
  <td>$row[5]</td>
  <td><A HREF=\"\">EDIT</A></td>
  <td><A HREF=\"\">DELETE</A></td>
  </tr>";
   }
  print "<tr style='background-color:#CDC9C9;'><td><A HREF=\"http://localhost/cgi- 
     bin/AddUser.cgi\">ADD</A></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>";
  print"</table>";
  $sth->finish();
  $dbh->commit();
  $dbh->disconnect;

  print <<END_HTML;
  <html>
  <head><title></title></head>
  <body>
  <form action="UsersList.cgi" method="get">
  <TABLE align="center">
  <TR>
  <TD align="left">
  <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="Submit">
  </TD>
  </TR>
  </TABLE>
  </form>
  </body></html>
  END_HTML

  ----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Please learn to format your questions correctly. All of the text is being formatted as code. It's probably putting some people off answering your questions.

Comment: Now you seem to have edited this post to remove your actual question. All we're left with is some code. That's not what I was suggesting at all :-)

Comment: It shows an amazing level of disrespect and contempt toward the people who will help you when you spend so little time preparing your question for the basics of spelling, formatting, never mind higher level concepts. Why should we spend time answering a question you don't take enough time to pose respectfully?

Comment: i beg sorry regarding the formating,,,i have no idea where to put the data and how..its just been a few days that i have become a member of this forum...i did not mean to disrespect anybody. am xtremely sorry sir..

Comment: I imagine you've been speaking english longer than a few days, and it's quite easy to see how to form sentences, use punctuation, and so on by looking at most posts here. Your problem is not anything to do with your newness to StackOverflow. We're quite happy to fix up posts for people who don't understand markdown.

Comment: jene, although it's for a different forum, much of the advice transfers:  http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=17974

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the (many) advantages that you'd get from using [DBIx::Class](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class/) for your database access is that all searches have built-in support for paging.

Alternatively, you might find something like [Data::Page](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Data-Page/) to be useful.

As for sorting, that's probably best done in your SQL query with a 'sort' clause.

Comment: i found dbix class rar file as wel as a data::page rar file...i downloaded them in my d drive but when i tried to use the code of paging then i got the error...why is that so? where am i supposed to save the rar file..?

Comment: Base class package "Class::Accessor::Chained::Fast" is empty.
    (Perhaps you need to 'use' the module which defines that package first,
    or make that module available in @INC (@INC contains: C:/Perl/site/lib C:/Perl/lib .).
 at C:/Perl/site/lib/Data/Page.pm line 4
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:/Perl/site/lib/Data/Page.pm line 4.
Compilation failed in require at C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/cgi-bin/UsersList.cgi line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/cgi-bin/UsersList.cgi line 7.

Comment: i had icluded this code in my program.. use Data::Page; my $page = Data::Page->new(); $page->total_entries($total_entries); $page->entries_per_page($entries_per_page); $page->current_page($current_page); print " First page: ", $page->first_page, "\n"; print " Last page: ", $page->last_page, "\n"; print "First entry on page: ", $page->first, "\n"; print " Last entry on page: ", $page->last, "\n";

Comment: Everything you need is on CPAN. I think you might want to go through _Learning Perl_ to learn the basics you seem to be missing.

Comment: You can also search StackOverflow to learn how to solve your additional problems.

Comment: If you're getting .rar files of CPAN modules then you're *so* looking in the wrong place. Try http://search.cpan.org/.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, first thing, get and read [Learning Perl](http://books.google.com/books?id=lNVHi3TunxsC&lpg=PP1&ots=2ZXVT7d63T&dq=learning%20Perl&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false).  It is, hands down, the best book to learn Perl with.

Next, take a look at [Ovid's CGI Course](http://jdporter.perlmonk.org/cgi_course/).

Third, your code has some major problems, and you'll need to walk before you run.

I've tidied and commented the heck out of your code.

```
#!C:\perl\bin\perl.exe

#  Windows perl ignores the shebang, except to check for flags and 
#  arguments to start the Perl interpreter with.
#  Your webserver might use it though

# You forgot to enable strict.  You enabled warnings further down in
# your code.  These two pragmas will help you write bug free code by 
# catching many errors.
#
# Keep your module and pragma usage at the top of your 
# scripts.  It aids readability. 

use strict;
use warnings;

# Using CGI is a good idea, but you only need to use CGI one time.
use CGI qw/:all/;

# These are good while learning and debugging.
# Do not use them in production code.
use CGI::Carp qw(warningsToBrowser fatalsToBrowser);

use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect(
    "dbi:SQLite:DEVICE.db",
    "", "",
    {
        RaiseError => 1,
        AutoCommit => 1
    }
);

# Don't use indirect object notation.  It can lead to subtle bugs.
# Use the arrow notation for method invocation instead.
my $q = CGI->new();
print $q->header ( );

# The @rows array was doing nothing.




# No need to commit when autocommit is on.
$dbh->commit();
$dbh->disconnect;

# Here we get the html table in a string.

my $table = generate_data_table( $dbi );

# And here we print your whole HTML block with the table interpolated
# into the the main text.  As it was, the HTML page was printing AFTER
# the table you generated.
#
# I put a crappy improper stylesheet in the header of your html page.
# Unless you are only doing the most rudimentary HTML work, learn to 
# use CSS properly.  Your time will be repayed hundreds of times over.
# For only rudimentary work, there's still a good chance you'll break 
# even on any time you invest in learning CSS.

print <<END_HTML;
<html>
<head>
    <title>Add Users</title>
    <style>
        .adduser {
            background-color:#CDC9C9;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="UsersList.cgi" method="get">

$table

    <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

</body>
</html>

END_HTML


# Use subroutines to group related actions.
sub generate_data_table {
    my $dbi = shift;

    my $sql = "SELECT UserId,UserName,CardNo,GroupId,Role,VerifyType FROM UsersList";

    my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql)
       or die("\n\nPREPARE ERROR:\n\n$DBI::errstr");

    $sth->execute 
        or die("\n\nQUERY ERROR:\n\n$DBI::errstr");

    # Actually generate the table HTML
    my $table = '<table><tr>';

    # Header
    $table .= join '', map "<th>$sth->{NAME}[$_]</th>\n", 0..5;
    $table .= "</tr>\n";

    # Normal Rows
    while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
        $table .= '<tr>',
        $table .= join '', map "<td>$row[$_]</td>\n", 0..5;

        $table .= join "\n", 
            '<td><A HREF=\"\">EDIT</A></td>'
            '<td><A HREF=\"\">DELETE</A></td>'
            "</tr>\n";
    }

    # Special Row
    #
    # Don't use inline CSS, use classes and either group all your css at
    # the top of your html code, or better yet, load an external stylesheet.

    # There is no reason to have to escape quotes when working with Perl CGI.
    # First, in html ' and " are interchangeable, so you can pick a quote
    # that doesn't need esacaping.
    #
    # Finally, if you MUST use both ' and " in a single string, you can use
    # Perl's quoting operators (q and qq) to select a safe delimiter that will allow you
    # to avoid escaping.

    $table .= 
          "<tr class='adduser' >"
        . '<td><a HREF="http://localhost/cgi-bin/AddUser.cgi">ADD</a></td>'
        . '<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>'
        . "</table>";

    $sth->finish();

    return $table;
}
```

Finally, to handle sorting and paging, you can use a library as others have suggested, or you can [modify your SQL query](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#select-stmt).  The keywords you want for grabbing only a range of results are `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`, use an `ORDER BY` clause to sort your result set.  Add some parameters to your forms to indicate what sorting methods or range you want.

Comment: Thanks a Lot for all your time and very very important information that you have provided me sir.Thanks a lot and yes you are right i need to have a strong basics before i move further,Thanks again.

Comment: CAN ANYBODY PLEASE TELL ME,WHY MY REPUTATION HAS GONE DOWN FROM 6 TO 1 OVERNIGHT?

Comment: jene, RELAX! SO gets a lot of posts that read like "How U do X?  Write me teh codez!".  Apparently, you've managed to get people to put you in this class.  I don't see it that way.  To me, your posts problems seem to stem from English being your 2nd language (based on some of your usage) and being overwhelmed by SO and Perl and CGI and HTML and CSS and SQL. Six big things to learn all at once.  In any case, SO seems to reward careful, formal writing.  In time your rep will recover. It sucks to be downvoted, but it calls your attention to a problem.  Too bad you have to guess what it might be.

Comment: Ok am a bit releived now after reading your comment. Even am trying hard to get a strong hold in all these Languages,especially "the Basics".Anyways i will try my best. And for my surprise my reputation has increased to 6 in overnight again,Amazing, Thanks a Lot.